# Android Changing Screen Brightness. Is a special permission required for this?

Tags: android

I need to change the Screen brightness on a single page to make QR Code reading easier.

I want to do this in the least invasive way possible for the user.  I don't really want to send them to the system settings just to make one activity brighter.  On the other hand I dont want to request additional permissions if there is a way around this?

Can I prompt the user to provide the permission dynamically on an as needed basis?  If not is there another permission that includes the `android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS` permission?

I am trying to reduce the total number of permissions required for the user.

Comment: You can change without permission as well. check this article https://androidacademic.blogspot.com/2023/03/change-android-screen-brightness.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's just for your application, I'm pretty sure you don't need to request a permission for it. To change the overall System brightness you do.

Here's a useful link I found:

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/02/change-android-screen-brightness.html

From the link:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
layoutParams.screenBrightness = BackLightValue;
getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
```

Comment: It seems to work.  How common is auto brightness? When does it get enabled/disabled?

Comment: Just depends on what the user has set. I don't know for sure that it DOESN'T work either; set your brightness to Auto, test it and see what happens. Also, seems to be from API Level 3: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#screenBrightness

Comment: it seems to work even when auto brightness is enabled.  It will reset brightness for that screen for as long as user is on the screen.  Thats all I needed.

Comment: It works even if "Auto Brightness" is enabled. As stated in the documentation, "screenBrightness can be used to override the user's preferred brightness of the screen". Tested on Android 4.1 and 4.4.

Comment: You can check this link too it has explained both ways with and without permission
https://androidacademic.blogspot.com/2023/03/change-android-screen-brightness.html